# Local message queue for sharing data between two processes

Tags: java, ipc, message-queue

I have a server application A that produces records as requests arrive. I want these records to be persisted in a database. However, I don't want to let application A threads spend time persisting the records by communicating directly with the database. Therefore, I thought about using a simple producers-consumers architecture where application A threads produce records and, another application B threads are the consumers that persist the records to the database.

I'm looking for the "best" way to share these records between applications A and B. An important requirement is that application A threads will always be able to send records to the IPC system (e.g. queue but that may be some other solution). Therefore, I think the records must always be stored locally so that application A threads will be able to send record event if network is down.

The initial idea that came to my mind was to use a local message queue (e.g. ActiveMQ). Do you think a local message queue is appropriate? If yes, do you recommend a specific message queue implementation? Note that both applications are written in Java.

Thanks, Mickael

Answer (score 1):

For this type of needs Queueing solution seems to be the best fit as the producer and consumer of the events can work in isolation. There are many solutions out there, and I have personally worked with RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ. Both are equally good. I don't wish to compare their performance characteristics here but RabbitMQ is written in Erlang which a language tailer-made for building real time applications.

Since you're already on Java platform ActiveMQ might be a better option and is capable producing high throughput. With a solution like this, the consumer does not have to be online all the time. Based on how critical your events data are, you may also want to have persistent queues and messages so that in the event of a message broker failure, you can still recover important "event" messages your application A produced.

If there are many applications producing events and later if you wish to [scale out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability)(or horizontally scale) the broker service because it's getting a bottleneck, both of the above solutions provide clustering services.

Last but not least, if you want to share these events between different platforms you may wish to share messages in [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/) format, which is a platform-independent wire-level protocol to share messages between heterogenous systems, and I'm not sure if this is requirement for you. RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ both support AMQP. Both of these solutions also support [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) which is a lightweight messaging protocol but it seems that you don't wish to use MQTT.

There are other products such as [HornetQ](http://hornetq.jboss.org/) and [Apache Qpid](https://qpid.apache.org/) which are also production ready solutions but I have not used them personally.

I think queueing solution is a the best approach in terms of maintainability, loose coupling nature of participating applications and performance.